# Go back main page fragment when user click "done"

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to go back to main page fragment when user click to 'Done' button. It can be like swifts' "dismiss()" function. However, I dont know what am I using like that function in android.

My code run like; open activity from fragment and this fragment load detail fragment.

First of all, the first fragments' adapter open the second fragments' activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_OFFER_DETAIL, binding.getController());
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

After that, activity open fragment automatically

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new DetailFragment(), null);
transaction.commit();
```

And I want to close last fragment when user click alert dialogs' done button

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
      getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); //That is what I tried but doesnt work
   }
});
```

Comment: You haven't pushed anything to the fragment manager's stack. So I would suggest using ```.addToBackStack(YOUR_FRAGMENT)``` when the activity opens the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about your activity and fragment workflow but to close the whole activity you can just call

```
finish();
```

to dismiss the whole activity.

Since there is no fragement in the backstack, `popBackStack()` won't do anything.
If you only wnat to dismiss the fragement, you should use:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```